# Is there a way to show all the App Store products from a company?

Tags: app-store, itunes

I tried SKStoreProductViewController but it seems it can only show one known products.I looked through the document of Search API and can't find a way to do this either.

Of course, I can do this by establishing my own database and put it in my server. But it would be better if I can do it in Apple's own way.Or is there a way to get the RSS feed for this?

Does anybody have any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Search API can help you do this - you just need to know the "artitstId" for the company.

Try this:

1. Lookup the "artistId" for a specific developer, I pulled it by looking up a single product by that artist.

   http://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?id=533451786
2. Now use the lookup API for that specific "artistId" and make sure to ask for the entity you want returned.

   http://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?id=298910979&entity=software,iPadSoftware,macSoftware
3. You can do the same for a Music artist as well.  Suppose you want all albums by Adele.

   http://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?id=262836961&entity=album